# React setState function and complex objects

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to wrap my head around the setState. I know the prefered method is to pass setState a function as the method is asynchronous and thus prevent overwritten state changes. So most often this works:

```
this.setState(() => ({title}))
```

but what if I have a complex object.
My state is like:

```
{
 movie: { name : 'one', length: 35},
 showLength: false
}
```

I want to be show the length based on a button click so I want to change the bool to true/false which is easy

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({showLength : !prevState.showLength}))
```

but what if I want to edit the name of the movie? Do I have to clone the entire state before I pass it to setState or is there a simpler method. I mean this does not work of cause (but shows my intent):

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({movie.title:'new title'}))
```

Comment: sorry for duplicated. called nested objects. Also had to add "transform-object-rest-spread" to babel to get it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you'll have to copy the contents of `movie` and then update the field you want.

This should work:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({...prevState.movie, title:'new title'}))
```

Answer (score 3):

`setState` can be used multiple ways. You can just pass in an object or you can pass a function inside which gets `prevState` as a parameter.

So this,

```
this.setState(() => ({title}))
```

actually same as doing this,

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return { title: title };
});
```

So this way you can make complicated changes to your state and return the new value.

**Example**

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  const newState = Object.assign({}, prevState);
  newState.movie.title = 'some new title';
  newState.showLength = !prevState.showLength;
  return newState;
});
```

Comment: hi perfect answer, I am new to react and is it true that conventional setState with object is asynchronous since it has reconciliation but functional setState is synchronous since it doesn't have reconciliation?

Comment: The "Example" is the thing I was looking for. Perfect indeed!